# Making a Simon Game, can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a Simon game, where the user follows an increasing sequence of randomly generated patterns and I almost finished it.

But I have this problem, at times that appear random the function nextSequence() seems to stop working, which ruins the game, because you are unable to see the next color you have to click on.

I have spend a lot of time trying to figure what is wrong but I just can't figure it out, usually it stops working correctly around level 5.

This is the function:

```
function nextSequence() {
  userClickPattern = [];

  level++;
  $("h1").text("Level " + level);

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  let randomChosenColor = buttonColors[random];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);

  $("#" + randomChosenColor)
    .fadeIn(100)
    .fadeOut(100)
    .fadeIn(100);

  makeSound(randomChosenColor);
}
```

I don't really know if that is the problem but I haven't been able to pinpoint anything else.

I'm pretty new in asking here and coding, if you need anything else or the question is unclear feel free to tell me how could I improve it.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/IgnacioGR/SimonGame

Here is the page: https://ignaciogr.github.io/SimonGame/

Comment: How does the game work? What is it supposed to do? What doesn’t work the way you expected? Can you share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example in the question itself?

Comment: The game executes the function nextSequence that takes one of the four colors randomly and adds it to the array gamePattern, then waits for the user to click on one of the colors and adds it in the array userClickPattern.

If both arrays have the same content it executes the function nextSequence again adding 1 to level so the arrays now have 2 "entries" and checks the user input against the gamePattern again.

If the input is incorrect the game ends.

The problem is that sometimes the random color doesn't blink so you don't have a visual cue to know which one you have to click.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain correctly, english is not my first language.

Comment: I think you need to have Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) because you only have 4 colors (so index options are 0, 1, 2, 3 but Math.random() * 5 would allow index of 4).

Comment: Yes I think that was it, so every time the random number was 4 that was giving me the error and that was why it was "random". I had  *4 before, guess I changed it without noticing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Change 5 to 4, you are only selecting between 4 colors only and your array index start with 0 and ends at 3.
At some point your code selects an index that out of color array boundaries.

Comment: Glade to help you